# Getting value from another feature depending on value of field using QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator

I'm a total newbie at coding.
I'm working with water catchments in QGIS. Runoff of some catchments feeds other catchments. I'm trying to get the cumulative run-off.

Each feature in the table has the following fields:

- `ID` - each polygon's number
- `Fed by` - the numerical ID of a polygon that feeds it
- `C` - the (calculated) runoff capacity of that field

I would like to create a field `C-in` that pulls the value of `C` from another feature based on the `ID` of that feature if it is written in `Fed by` field.

I imagine it is something along the lines of: When `Fed by` equals the value of an `ID`, get `C` of that `ID`, for example:

[image]

In particular, we have:

- `ID`: 19, `Fed by`: 9, `C`: 0.5
- `ID`: 20, `Fed by`: 19, `C`: 0.7

So `C-in` of `ID=20` should be: 0.5 (forget for a moment the `C-in` of `ID=19`)

So what do I need to write in the field calculator to get this magic to happen?

Answer (score 8):

Try the following expression:

```
attribute(get_feature(@layer_id,'id',"fed by"),'C')
```

The `get_feature` call finds the feature in the current layer whose `id` is equal to the current feature's `fed by`. Note double quotes on `fed by` since the value of this field for the current feature should be evaluated in the expression. However `id` has single quotes since it is a parameter to `get_feature` to tell it what field *name* to use, and should not be replaced by the current feature's `id` (20 in your example). Then `attribute` pulls out the value of `C` in that feature (not double quotes for same reason as before, to avoid it being replaced by 0.7 during evaluation).

**Nonanswer**

I was all set to suggest you create a join (in Layer Properties) to the same layer and then link on the `fed by` field. But it seems QGIS doesn't permit self-joins.

**Remark**

You could probably save some work, if you haven't gone too far down this path yet, by instead adding a field describing what each catchment flows in to, and then using the `aggregate` function to find and sum over all (sub)catchments that flow into your catchment. This would replace your multiple `fed by #` fields, but the linkage would go the other way (upstream links to single downstream, rather than downstream links to several upstream).

And all of this gets a bit more complicated if you have multiple layers of `fed-by`s, i.e. A feeds into B which feeds into C. Your current logic -- or my alternative in this remark -- will work if A and B both feed into C, not if they're nested, so to speak.